# Return list of rows if all records exist in another table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

Simple query in theory but I can't get my head around the required syntax, not sure what this type if query is called / how to word it which is making it difficult to google for a solution. SQL Server 2014

I basically want to return a list of user IDs if all of their records exist within another table.

Example

Users

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 |
| 2 | User2 |
| 3 | User3 |
| 4 | User4 |
| 5 | User5 |

UserRecords

| ID | UserId | Record |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 50 |
| 101 | 1 | 52 |
| 102 | 1 | 55 |
| 103 | 2 | 50 |
| 104 | 2 | 52 |
| 105 | 2 | 55 |
| 106 | 2 | 60 |
| 107 | 3 | 50 |
| 108 | 3 | 55 |
| 109 | 3 | 61 |
| 110 | 4 | 50 |
| 111 | 4 | 55 |
| 112 | 4 | 60 |
| 113 | 5 | 60 |

Lookup Table

| ID |
| --- |
| 50 |
| 55 |
| 60 |

Expected results

| UserId |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |

I want 'Expect Results' to show a list of UserIds where all Id in 'Lookup' (another table) appear in 'UsersResults' for each user. User '2' has an additional record in UserRecords that is not in 'Lookup' but I still want their Id returned in list of valid results

If I knew the type of query this is I can probably find the answer myself

Thank you

Comment: The term you are looking for is [Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` and `group by`.  Assuming you have no duplicates in `userrecords` (as in your sample data):

```
select ur.userid
from userrecords ur join
     lookup lu
     on ur.record = lu.id
group by ur.userid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from lookup);
```

If you do have duplicates in `userrecords`, then use `count(distinct record)`.

Comment: Thankyou, sorry, should have added additional information. There will be duplicate records in UserRecords but there is another column to identify if the record is archived so I can filter on that. Thank you, I shall try your suggestion

Comment: @JimmyDC . . . Just include the filter in the `where` clause.